# Setting asp.net MVC4 web api route url in javascript is returning empty string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

Here is the code that I am using to set the api url:

```
var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Client"})';
```

In my route.config the route looks like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        );
```

And the action on my controller that I am trying to hit is this:

```
[ActionName("clients")]
    public IQueryable<Client> GetClients(int id)
    {
        return Uow.Clients.GetClients(id);
    }
```

I have a function in javascript that is trying to hit this api, but I am getting a 404:

```
var getClients = function (id) {
            return $.ajax(clientUrl + "/clients/" + id)
        };
```

When I call getClients(1) the url is trying to hit is this:

```
localhost:12345/clients/1
```

Rather than my expected url of this:

```
localhost:12345/api/client/clients/1
```

Any idea where this is going wrong? I had this working in another project and can't remember if there is something else I am supposed to do. If I inspect the javascript the clientUrl = ''.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came across this answer [How to create ASP.NET Web API Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502306/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-web-api-url) which helped.

Example code for my answer here on [GitHub](https://github.com/markyjones/StackOverflow/tree/master/ApiControllerRouteUrlExample)

You can alter your @Url.RouteUrl code to include **both** the action name and the "ID" which currently appears not to be optional for your action route... this is probably why it is failing to find a match and returning an empty string. So try:

```
var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Client", action = "clients" id=@... })';
```

**NB.** `id=@... })';` at the end ... being what ever the id is going to be var or property on a model etc...

### **Or**

You could of course just make ID optional which will also work:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiControllerAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

### **Or**

You may find it cleaner to avoid using an action... clients could live in its own controller `ClientsController` and you can use the routes and defaults to route to it:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiControllerAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/client/clients/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller="Clients" }
    );
```

Then this should give you the required response:

```
var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Clients" })';

//api/client/clients/
```

and...

```
var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Clients", id=@... })';

//api/client/clients/x
```

Comment: THanks for the thorough answer. I will check this out tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `clientUrl` like this:

```
var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Client", action = "clients"})';
```

And then in change `getClients` to this:

```
var getClients = function (id) {
    return $.ajax(clientUrl + "/" + id)
};
```

Comment: I am not even hitting the controller in this code though. Well not yet. My issue is will getting that route into a variable in javascript that I can use.

Comment: Don't you need the action specified in the call to `Url.RouteUrl`?

Comment: I do that in my getClients js functions. I have a few different api controllers in my project, so I am trying to put each in a variable that I can then get to the different actions within. So I am trying to get www.domain.com/api/client from my Url.RouteUrl, but it is not find it for some reason.

Comment: even putting in the action does not do it for some reason. I feel like the razor line is not being called corrected because it is giving me back an empty string. Ideally i would like this to work without an explicit action call however. Any thoughts?