# How to create url for MVC action from ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to create an url that liks to an MVC action from an ApiController?  I see examples of doing this the other way around, to reach ApiController from with MVC using MVC's UrlHelper (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/17/using-the-asp-net-web-api-urlhelper.aspx).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502306/how-to-create-asp-net-web-api-url

Comment: hmm, not sure if i'm missing something, but the link you sent to is to route to an API url from within MVC.  I want the other way around, route to MVC url from with API controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Url property on the API controller to find a route to a web api or an MVC controller.  Here is an example of creating a link to the default project template MVC method AccountController.Login(string returnURL).

```
    public class SOExampleController : ApiController
{

    public SOExample GetSOExample()
    {
        var url = Url.Route("Default", new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", returnUrl = "hello"});
        return new SOExample{URL = url};
    }
}

public class SOExample
{
    public string URL {get;set;}
}
```

When ran you get the url value of the "/Account/Login?returnUrl=hello".   It looks like you may need to prepend the domain, which should be trivial to find.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  It didn't work for me the first time because I didn't supply all of the parameters.  Thanks again.

Comment: Done! Sorry for being a noob!