# KendoUI Grid with MVC Wrappers and Web API

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI grid with ASP.Net MVC Wrappers.  My grid datasource is defined as follows:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.Code);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Url("api/ProjectMilestone").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url("api/ProjectMilestone").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url("api/ProjectMilestone").Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url("api/ProjectMilestone").Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
      )
```

So one would expect that the GET url would be generated as `[server]/[app]/api/ProjectMilestone`.

But in my case, the page on which the grid is hosted is at the following URL: `[server]/[app]/Project`.
This results in the GET url being generated as `[server]/[app]/Project/api/ProjectMilestone`, and of course the server returns error 404 not found.

Please tell me how I can have the GET url generated as `[server]/[app]/api/ProjectMilestone` instead.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not believe that server-side Kendo UI wrappers support WebApi calls. You must use the JavaScript implementations of Kendo UI instead.

Comment: @Brett they certainly do support WebApi calls, and have released a demo project to show this: http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/binding-to-a-web-apicontroller.aspx

Comment: Also, in this demo project I can replicate the problem.  I will log it with Telerik support.

Comment: Ah ok, good. I knew in earlier versions they did not have that support, but I'm glad they added it. I hope your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the correct approach is to define the datasource as follows:

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute ="", controller="ProjectMilestone" })).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
.Create(create => create.Url(Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute ="", controller="ProjectMilestone" })).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
.Update(update => update.Url(Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute ="", controller="ProjectMilestone" })).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute ="", controller="ProjectMilestone" })).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
```

as taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502480/10141) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the overload that takes a Controller name and action using "api" for the controller and "ProjectMilestone" for the action?

Comment: He wants his Kendo UI server wrappers to call his WebApi controller named ProjetMilestone. What you are suggesting is that he create an MVC controller named 'api'. That is wrong.

Comment: I am not suggesting he create a controller.  That overload simply concatenates the strings together.  So, if you have say, http://myserver/myarea/something and your view has .Read(read => read.Action("ProjectMilestone", "api"), then the AJAX request will have the url http://myserver/myarea/api/ProjectMilestone