# ASP.NET API Not Found If Not On Main View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have an ApiController that is in my simple MVC project (.Net 4.5.2, MVC 5.2.3, EF 6.1.3, API 2.2).  It is shown here:

```
namespace MyApplication.PM.Controllers.API
{
    public class ApplicationUserContactAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: api/ApplicationUserContactAPI/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Contact))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetContact(Guid id)
        {
            Contact contact = await db.Contacts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ApplicationUserID == id);
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the route by default (was added when I added an API):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I am calling this API via ajax on my partial view (out-of-the-box _LoginPartial.cshtml) like so:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var uri = 'api/ApplicationUserContactAPI';
            var userid = '@User.Identity.GetUserId()';

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON(uri + '/' + userid)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        $('.manageAccount').text('Hello ' + data.FirstName + '!');
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                        alert('error: ' + err);
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

If I login and I am on my main view (start debugging), the call to the API is fine.  If i click on one of the standard links (again, out-of-the-box from template), I get a "Not Found" message.  Is this a routing issue and if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try once with absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate your link by helper *Url.Action* method:

```
var uri = '@Url.Action("GetContact", "ApplicationUserContactAPI", new { httproute = "" })';
```

Here's related problem: [click!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502306/how-to-create-asp-net-web-api-url)

Comment: Thanks @MacGyver!  I knew there had to be a better way of doing it than the Request.ApplicationPath method.