# WebAPI 2 attribute routing with areas need to generate url in different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a trouble to generate webApi Url in mvc view.

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

ApiController

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/bikes")]
public class bikesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("", Name = "PostBike")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBike([FromBody]Bike bike)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

area registration

```
public override string AreaName 
{
    get 
    {
        return "V1";
    }
}
```

So the question is how to get absolute url (PostBike) in 
`OtherController : Controller`(its in the same area 'V1') View

I have tried many variations, and they don't work.
thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ASP.NET Web API Url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502306/how-to-create-asp-net-web-api-url)

Comment: it is similar but not the same. I don't have named mapping.